# Singleton pattern implementation

Tags: objective-c, ios, singleton

I've seen this particular implementation of the *singleton pattern* everywhere:

```
+ (CargoBay *)sharedManager {
   static CargoBay *_sharedManager = nil;
   static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
   dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
      _sharedManager = [[CargoBay alloc] init];
   });
   return _sharedManager;
}
```

and it seems to be accepted as good practice (this one in particular is from [CargoBay](https://github.com/mattt/CargoBay)).

The only part I don't understand is the first line `static CargoBay *_sharedManager = nil;`.

Why are you setting that `static` variable to `nil`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just a matter of readability, convention and practice. It's not really needed, because:

One. Its value won't ever be checked. In older singleton implementations there used to be the famous

```
+ (id)sharedInstance
{
    static SomeClass *shared = nil;
    if (shared == nil)
        shared = [[SomeClass alloc] init];

    return shared;
}
```

code - for this method to work, the backing variable has to be initialized to nil, since if it wasn't nil for the first time, it would falsely omit the alloc-init in the if part and return a junk pointer. However, with the GCD solution, the nil-check is not anymore needed - GCD handles the 'execute this code only once' pragma.

Two. But nevertheless: static variables are implicitly initialized to zero. So even if you just write `static id shared;` it will initially be `nil`.

Three. Why this might be good practice? Because, despite the first two reasons I mentioned, it's still more readable to let the reader of the source code know that something is explicitly initialized to zero. Or there may even exist some non-conforming implementations where static variables are not properly autoinitialized, and then this action shall be taken.

Comment: @Francesco What do you mean by?

Comment: By declaring the shared instance `static` we are extending its lifetime to the one of the entire application, right?

The point of the Singleton pattern is to have a shared instance that can be used everywhere in our application, but why are we creating a new instance every time we call that method?

Comment: @Francesco you're seriously missing understanding of how all this works. **The code you posted *does not* create a new instance every time you call the method. It creates an instance first time, and returns that very same instance every time onwards.**

Comment: See the back-and-forth below my post.  It will not be created each time we call the method.  If you want to make that obvious to a reader/reviewer, move the declaration of the shared instance outside the code block itself (see my second code block).

Comment: Now I think I'm beginning to understand. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting it to nil to ensure you are getting a clean instance.

This is a more readable version of what you want to do:

```
+ (GlobalVariables *)sharedInstance {
    // the instance of this class is stored here
    static GlobalVariables *myInstance = nil;

    // check to see if an instance already exists
    if (nil == myInstance) {
        myInstance  = [[[self class] alloc] init];
    }
    // return the instance of this class
    return myInstance;
}
```

But there are loads of posts around showing how this can potentially not be thread-safe, so moving to a hybrid of your method above and what I posted, you get this:

```
// Declared outside Singleton Manager    
static SingletonClass *myInstance = nil;
+ (GlobalVariables *)sharedInstance {
    if (nil != myInstance) {
        return myInstance;
    }

    static dispatch_once_t pred;        // Lock
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{             // This code is called at most once per app
        myInstance = [[GlobalVariables alloc] init];
    });

    return myInstance;
}
```

Comment: "The block of code you reference is not going to always re-use the same instance" - this is just *not true.*

Comment: the code that is covered by the GCD to execute only once is what is within the dispatch_once block, not the assignment which is outside of it.  The gist of what I wrote was attempting to improve readability by simply adding a check of the shared instance.  Moving the assignment of the shared instance outside the Singleton accessor makes the whole process clean.

Comment: that 'assignment' is not really an 'assignment' but rather an initialization. And because the variable being initialized is `static`, ***it will be executed (initialized) exactly once, regardless of its scope, where it is declared/initialized, etc.*** Wikipedia's [very first example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable) clearly states that *"x is initialized only once across three calls of func()"...*

Comment: THanks for the link to Wikipedia, I guess even if the instance is accessed by two requestors simultaneously, iOS makes sure that they do not step on each other.  I was merely trying to provide a more readable version of the pattern that could be easily understood.  I will edit my answer to remove the statement you have issue with.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is exactly that iOS doesn't "make sure" the calls don't collapse - theat's why solution #1 (the classic one) isn't thread safe.